# How to detect if user did a screenshot with home+power in iOS?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, screenshot

I'm trying to detect if user take a screenshot in order to warn them this is a video with copyright. I've tried Darwin Notification, but it didn't work...
NSMetadataQuery might be a solution, but we want the app to run on iOS4 as well. Can somebody help me? 
Thanks!:p

Comment: @jjmontes While it's a technically valid question, it's an anti-user "feature", like websites that block right-clicking. It's just as likely to piss people off as it is to effectively protect anyone's IP.

Comment: oops...I won't do anything to prevent user doing what they want to do. Such as capture screen or watch video. Just warning them about the copyright things :[

Comment: [This question][1] has [the correct answer][2].

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13484516/ios-detection-of-screenshot
  [2]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14120549/9636

Answer (score 2):

**It is not possible to detect a screenshot has (or will) be taken on iOS 5.**

In iOS 4.0, there was a Darwin notification fired `PictureWasTakenNotification`, but not anymore.

The documentation does not mention anything, and using `NSNotificationCenter` to subscribe to all notifications only shows silence after taking a screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

before ios 4.0 you can register for `PictureWasTakenNotification` .This notification is sent when screenshot is taken.No notifications will be sent before the screenshot was taken.
But after that this has been discontinued and IMHO there is no other way round... :/

Answer (score 1):

you can detect it with adding an observer to `UIApplicationUserDidTakeScreenshotNotification` .

```
NSOperationQueue *mainQueue = [NSOperationQueue mainQueue];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserverForName:UIApplicationUserDidTakeScreenshotNotification
              object:nil
               queue:mainQueue
          usingBlock:^(NSNotification *note) {
             // executes after screenshot
}];
```