# Can you protect content by not letting people screen capture in IOS?

Tags: ios, screenshot

As my title says, is it possible to protect content in an app from being screen captured? Can you make an app notice when someone is trying to take a screenshot(photo) and replace the UI(view) with empty content ?

Answer (score 2):

Short: Sort of. See this answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14120549/322548

Long: You can protect your content by hiding passwords, etc. before a screenshot is taken or before your app goes to the background. However, detecting screenshots isn't as easy as it sounds. Until iOS 6 you can at least detect a screenshot being taken (see link above), but this might change with any new iOS release.