# Sending screenhots to server immediately on background

Tags: ios, objective-c, background-process

I have two questions:

- Is it possible to create an app that upload screenshots to a server when the user takes one? It should also upload screenshots when another app is active.
- If an app like this is possible, will apple allow this to their appstore?

I want to create an app like this to provide remote support to users so that we know what the user see on their device.

Comment: This might be useful for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13484516/ios-detection-of-screenshot

Answer (score 0):

You can detect when a screenshot is done: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18158483/1034126

And then programatically take another one and upload to the server: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2203293/1034126

But I don't think that's a good approach. You shouldn't need to take an screenshot to upload one, you can use a `UIButton`to trigger the programatic screenshot and then upload it to the server.