# How to simulate taking a screenshot in iOS simulator?

Tags: ios, ios-simulator

Is there any way to simulate taking a screen shot on iOS simulator (equivalent of home + power on device)? My goal is NOT to save (cmd + s) or copy a shot of screen (from simulator menu items) but to capture UIApplicationUserDidTakeScreenshotNotification event.

Comment: could you describe more about it. what you tried!

Comment: Updated the answer. I have already tried saving the screen shot or copying the scree from simulator menu but none of them triggered the handler for UIApplucationUserDidTakeScreenshotNotification.

Comment: could you refer this link [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13484516/ios-detection-of-screenshot)

Answer (score 16):

Use LLDB to mimic the screenshot NSNotification:

```
(lldb) expr [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:(NSNotificationName)UIApplicationUserDidTakeScreenshotNotification object:nil]
```

Pass `--ignore-breakpoints false --` to the `expr` command if you want to stop at a breakpoint too:

```
(lldb) expr --ignore-breakpoints false -- [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:(NSNotificationName)UIApplicationUserDidTakeScreenshotNotification object:nil]
```

Comment: Here is steps for programmatically invoke `UIApplicationUserDidTakeScreenshotNotification`.

1. When Xcode debugging click the `Pause` Button (It between the `Deactivate breakpoint` button and `Step over` button).
2. The app will the enter paused states and shows `(lldb)` prompt (like stop at breakpoint).
3. Then, enter the that command `expr [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:(NSNotificationName)UIApplicationUserDidTakeScreenshotNotification object:nil]`
4. Don't forgot to press play button to continue process running.

Comment: I could not get this to work in latest Xcode 11 / iOS 13.

Answer (score 4):

No, this is not currently possible in the iOS Simulator.

Comment: It is possible if you attach a debugger. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I too not able to detect UIApplicationUserDidTakeScreenshotNotification, But why dont you use this code to take screen shots and detect them using conditions.

```
//    // TAKE SCREENSHOT
CGRect myRect = [self.view bounds];
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(myRect.size);
CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
[[UIColor blackColor] set];
CGContextFillRect(ctx, myRect);
[self.view.layer renderInContext:ctx];
UIImage *viewimage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(viewimage, 1.0);
if(imageData!=NULL)
{
   NSLog(@"user saved the image");
//Here you can detect the screen shots
   [self.imagevieww setImage:[UIImage imageWithData:imageData]];
}
else
{
   NSLog(@"user dont want to save image");
}
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```