# Detecting screencasting on iOS

Tags: ios, screenshot, snapchat, screencast

The [CyberDust](https://www.cyberdust.com/) app (similar to Snapchat) detects when it is being screencast (even via a Quicktime recording according to [this article](http://www.businessinsider.com/how-to-record-snapchats-without-anyone-knowing-2014-12)).

What API makes this possible?

[image]

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13484516/ios-detection-of-screenshot

Comment: @BensonTommy that question is about taking screenshots. This one is about screencasting.