# Message when user take screen shot by js

Tags: javascript, html

I am working on a web app (html and js) for smartphones  and i need to give the user a message while taking a screen shot .
Is it possible  and if there are any example codes

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iOS Detection of Screenshot?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13484516/ios-detection-of-screenshot)

Comment: @Guy Not really, that's for native apps, not web based stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it is very tricky to say if possible to detect screenshot event by javaScript as screenshot event is belongs to the OS and not web browser. So javascript wouldn't be detect this event.

Another way is that find out ASCII table which is the screenshot key on the keyboard. But I don't think it will helpful.