# Can my app know when user have done a screenshot and access it in the background (ios)?

Tags: ios, swift, mobile, screenshot

If my app has access to the Photos folder can I catch the moment when user have done a screenshot (of any other app) and access it in the background?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/18158483/1226963 but I don't know if it works while your app is in the background.

Comment: Thanks. Saw this thread. The background is the key for me. I doubt if it's possible but want to check with the community.

Comment: Try it. It will be faster than waiting for an answer.