# Is it possible to take screenshots globally on the iPhone and save it on an app?

Tags: iphone, swift, screenshot

I wondered if it is possible to take a screenshot on an iPhone (newest versions of iOS) gloablly (in any app) and save it on a specific app that manages the screenshots and saves them in specific folders instead of the default photo album.

I searched the App Store for such apps but couldn't find anything that suited my needs.

Thx.

Comment: No since your app can interacte with the system to make a screen shot in the background.

Comment: You can set your app to get all photos from Screenshots file in photo library

Comment: @0ndre_ is it possible to make the app recognize screenshots only in some way or does it download all photos?

Comment: You can only change screenshot destinations on OSX or in simulator. You aren't alowed to change the destination to anything other than the photo library. You can use `NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserverForName(UIApplicationUserDidTakeScreenshotNotification()` for screenshot detection

Comment: more info here http://stackoverflow.com/a/18158483/6448167