# Xamarin iOS: Disable screenshot option

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am working on an app which has very sensitive data, which we do not want to be saved anywhere. In Android we can disable taking screenshot. Is there a way to do the same on iOS? 
I do not want any user who access sensitive information to try to take screenshot.

PS. i am using xamarin forms to create the app, but if this functionality can be achieved through objective C/ swift, they can always be achieved through xamarin.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot prevent users from taking screenshots on iOS. However, since your concerns are security related, one thing you might want to consider is preventing the OS from displaying a screenshot of your app in the recently used apps list when users have the app minimised, which can be done. To do so (using Xamarin), you need to override `OnResignActivation` and `OnActivated` in your `AppDelegate`:

```
// Hide app state in recently used apps list
public override void OnResignActivation(UIApplication application)
{
    var view = new UIView(Window.Frame)
    {
        Tag = new nint(101),
        BackgroundColor = UIColor.White
    }
    Window.AddSubview(view);
    Window.BringSubviewToFront(view);
}

// Remove window hiding app content when app is resumed
public override void OnActivated(UIApplication application)
{
    var view = Window.ViewWithTag(new nint(101));
    view?.RemoveFromSuperview();
}
```

I realise this doesn't answer your question, but it may be as much as can be done.

Answer (score 2):

There is really no way you can prevent a user from taking a screenshot, it is simply not allowed in iOS. What you could do, however, is perform actions when you are able to detect a screenshot was taken.

This is probably as good as it gets. I don't have a Xamarin solution, this is how you would do it in Swift: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18158483/4660602

The user provides an answer for both Obj-c and Swift, so you if you can port that code over to Xamarin successfully, you can perform some intuitive actions after a screenshot is taken, because you cannot prevent the user from taking one.