# Prohibit screenshot inside an App on iOS

Tags: ios, screenshot

I'm looking for a way to prohibit iOS taking screenshots of my App. I would like to blurr or color the screen when I take a screenshot of my App. I'm already able to change the appearance of the screen when sending the App to the background (double home tap). Is there any way to achieve this?

Best regards,
SynTraX

Answer (score 1):

Someone has already asked that question and that can be found here: [ios-detection-of-screenshot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13484516/ios-detection-of-screenshot)