# can we Disable taking screenshots in own app ? using objective-c,xcode?

Tags: objective-c, iphone, xcode, screenshot

I want to make an app in which users can't take screenshots,so is it possible in objective-c?

Comment: No this isn't possible. What you can do maximum is [getting a notification when user takes a screenshot](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18158483/3687801)

Comment: Please [search](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bios%5D+disable+screenshot) before posting.

Comment: ok. thx @rmaddy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not prevent taking screenshots entirely. But You can do what Snapchat does, that will be requiring the user to be touching the screen to view whatever information you're displaying. This is because the system screenshot event interrupts touches. It's not a perfect method and you can't prevent users from taking screenshots 100% of the time.

More details: [iOS Detection of Screenshot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13484516/ios-detection-of-screenshot)