# Is it possible to detect screenshot in background for iOS?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, screenshot

I am trying to get the screenshot event in iOS while app is in background but not able to find any proper API functions for this.

Can anyone please help for this?

Thanks

Comment: Yes.
Please, look at this answer.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13484516/ios-detection-of-screenshot

Comment: Add an observer for: `UIApplicationUserDidTakeScreenshotNotification`

Comment: I have tried this function already but its App only so if App is open then i can  detect the event of screenshot but I need solution if my app is in background & take screenshot of website opened in safari browser then its not working using - UIApplicationUserDidTakeScreenshotNotification

Comment: I think after long search i can say that Apple does not allow to detect screenshot if our app is in background but any help can be appreciated if possible.

Thanks