# How to detect a screenshot in a RN application?

Tags: react-native, screenshot

I'm having some problem about a screenshot-detector in an application.

I'm using **EXPO**, but I've no idea about how can I detect a screenshot.
Suppose that I've a profile screen. Each user has a profile page, I want to detect when another user does a screenshot on the screen.

My problem is: how can I detect this? I readed about the **gesture** [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/gesture-responder-system), but it didn't help me. With the gestures I can detect, instead, the scroll in a page, **the location x and location y**.

I readed also this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18158483/7942000), but about the event `touchesCancelled:withEvent:touchesCancelled:withEvent:` I have not found anything in React Native docs (and also EXPO docs).

So: which is the idea behind a screenshot detector? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do it without detaching EXPO. There is already a [feature request](https://expo.canny.io/feature-requests/p/detect-user-screenshots) for that.

If you decide to detach EXPO, [react-native-screenshot-detector](https://github.com/blend/react-native-screenshot-detector) might be helpful. The solution is very similar to the one from the linked question.

Answer (score 0):

Currently with expo there is no way to do that, But if you detach you can use this package it supports android&ios screenshot detecting [react-native-detector](https://github.com/AzizAK/react-native-detector)