# Restrict user to take screenshot in iOS App

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, user-controls, screenshot

I can detect user attempt to take screenshot but unable to restrict him to take screenshot. My Code is provided below

```
NSOperationQueue *mainQueue = [NSOperationQueue mainQueue];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserverForName:UIApplicationUserDidTakeScreenshotNotification
                                                  object:nil
                                                   queue:mainQueue
                                              usingBlock:^(NSNotification *note) {
    
    [self.delegate screenShotDetected];
    
                                              }];
```

Is there any technique or code to disable screenshot in the app?

Comment: You can not stop a user from taking a screenshot on his device but you can manage the content that is taken when your app is active or inactive (background). `UIScreenshotServiceDelegate` the service can be found always (nonnull) `self.view.window.windowScene.screenshotService` (iOS13)

Comment: @zeytin when I able to solve it I will definately share  the solution.

Comment: ok my answer wasn't helpful ?

Answer (score 1):

**No you can`t**. Because you have not access to delete photos in the photo gallery of the user. It would be a security gap if it happened.

But, there are some inefficient ways which is used in SnapChat as written in the link, you can check out.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13484516/ios-detection-of-screenshot