# Prevent screenshots and video record of screen for iOS Ionic app

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, screenshot

I am developing an Ionic app for Android and iOS.

We are trying to prevent users from taking screenshots of the app, whether the method is blurring the screen or otherwise. We also want to prevent video screen recording.

We are building using Ionic, so the method must work with Ionic.

We have been able to get this to work for Android, but not iOS.

Anyone know of any Ionic-friendly methods to prevent screen shots while inside an app?

Comment: there is a way used in snapchat : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13484516/ios-detection-of-screenshot

Comment: Thanks but this doesn't exactly fit our use case. We don't want to do anything like force the user to hold down on the screen to see the app screens. We just want to prevent screenshots. We found examples that work in native or other platforms but nothing yet for Ionic.

Comment: @JamesBroyles If you found native code that works why don't you just write a custom Cordova plugin using plugman or similar?