# Apply watermark on screenshot in Xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am creating a xamarin forms app, where i need to implement that if user takes screenshot then, a watermark should appear on that screenshot.
The watermark should appear only on screenshot not in whole app.
If it is possible then please help me.

Any advice or suggestion will be great help for me.
Thank You.

Comment: https://blog.aspose.com/2021/03/08/add-watermark-to-images-in-csharp/

Answer (score 0):

While preventing screenshots is more or less possible on Android (https://stackoverflow.com/a/31406316/16607977) there's no API to detect or manipulate the screenshot. [Here's](https://proandroiddev.com/detect-screenshots-in-android-7bc4343ddce1?gi=68412c0ca1c7) a description of a workaround to detecting screenshots, which boils down to watching the filesystem for new files with "screenshot" in their path - you might try to access and manipulate this file then. If the user does not give you permissions, this won't work.

For iPhone, you might also detect the screen capture (https://stackoverflow.com/a/18158483/16607977), somehow identify the file and add the watermark. I doubt this will be easy without the user's permission.