# Delphi iOS avoid screenshot

Tags: ios, delphi, screenshot

I want to avoid taking a screenshot of one particular form for iOS. On Android I found a way to avoid this but for iOS it seems this is an OS function which can't be used. Does anyone have experiences with this in Delphi or have found a way that works?

Comment: What does that even mean? Do you want to prevent the user from taking a screenshot of a particular form? Maybe once you get the wording straight, you'll get proper Google results.

Comment: Yes, I want to prevent the user from taking a screenshot of a particular form.

Answer (score 0):

It is always helpful to look around what developers using swift are writing on such topics:

You can see in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18680028/prevent-screen-capture-in-an-ios-app#:%7E:text=In%20fact%2C%20there%20is%20no,party%20library%20for%20the%20same.&text=yes%20there%20is%20no%20way,is%20no%20mechanism%20besides%20this.) question, it is also tricky in swift to do this. You could try catching the interruption of the touchscreen like suggested in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13484516/ios-detection-of-screenshot). You would have to do some research on how to catch iOS events for this.